# pHp/htaccess 301 Redirect rewrite for dynamic page & friendly url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a page, Product1.php, that is dynamic for populating my products from a database. I have searched and searched, including at this site, but been unable to ascertain a solution that exactly addresses the 301 redirect I need which will retain my custom friendly url rubric **while forcing the user and bot to it in lieu of the query string**?

All my query string urls are as such:

```
http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=1
http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=2
http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=3
```

This is the rubric I have the rewritten urls to follow, based on the column names in my database:

```
http://www.example/category/subcategory/model_name-model_id/product_id
```

Here is the htaccess function I have written to make the rewrite work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^.*/.*/.*/([0-9]+)$ Product1.php?Product_ID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

These rewritten urls are already in place and fully functional. **What I can't figure out is how to write the redirect so that the user is forced to see the SEO-friendly url when she types in** `http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=1`**, or when the search-engine bot crawls my page.**

Thanks in advance!

EDITED for clarity
FURTHER EDIT for clarity -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "category", "subcategory" and "model_name-model_id" in your URL before you start any redirection like this. At the moment I cannot see anything like that (Product1.php?=Product_ID=1) If you have them you can use

RewriteCond
..
.. 
RewriteRule

kind of method for this.

Comment: My urls are presently http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/model_name-model-id/product_id. The rewrite is already in place and fully functional. What I can't figure out is how to write the redirect so that the user is forced to see the SEO-friendly url when she types it in http://www.example.com/Product1.php?=Product_ID=2, or when the search-engine bot crawls my page. Sorry if I'm obscure.

Comment: Try [R=301,L] instead of [L,QSA]

Comment: Chathuraka, I tried that and I was getting 404 errors.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)+/(.*)+/(.*)+/([0-9]+)$ Product1.php?Product_ID=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ Product1.php?Product_ID=$4 [L,QSA] this should work

Comment: Chathuraka, this gave me a 500 internal server error

Comment: Why $4 at the end of the string instead of $1?

Comment: Chathuraka, your second function also does not work, more 404 errors